# How can check equality of 2 tables by specified id fields?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[M_FirstTable](
-- ...
[SomeId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
-- ...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[M_SecondTable](
-- ...
[SomeId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
-- ...
)
```

How can I check: is this two table equal by all SomeId field of their items?

For example: if FirstTable = {{SomeId = 1}, {SomeId = 2}} and SecondTable = {{SomeId = 1}}, then this two tables are not eqaul, because there is not element with SomeId = 2 in SecondTable.

Comment: The proposed answers return the differences between tables, not just an equal/not equal result.  They should be wrapped in [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) to provide a boolean result and give the optimizer a chance to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Select SomeId From FirstTable

Except

Select SomeId From SecondTable

Union All

Select SomeId From SecondTable

Except

Select SomeId From FirstTable
```

This will generate a resultset of all rows in FirstTable that are not in SecondTable and all rows in the SecondTable that are not in FirstTable.

Comment: I think about it. But see this case:
FirstTable = {{SomeId = 1}}
SecondTable = {{SomeId = 1}, {SomeId = 2}}
And Except comand using return empty collection (what assume equality of 2 tables), but they are not equal.
And in this way we must also use except command by exception SecondTable elements from FirstTable.
And after all we must see zero count of resultset of two this queries.
I just think maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: @RustamSalahutdinov - You are right. Take a look at my correction. If no rows are returned, both tables are equal.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a useful query too :

```
SELECT a.[SomeId],
       b.[SomeId]
FROM   M_FirstTable a
       FULL OUTER JOIN M_SecondTable b
                    ON a.[SomeId] = b.[SomeId]
WHERE  a.[SomeId] IS NULL
        OR b.[SomeId] IS NULL
```

1. when a.[SomeId] is not null then it is present only in first table.

2. when b.[SomeId] is not null then it is present only in second table.

Comment: I would love to hear what is wrong in this so that I will keep that in mind next time ? (downvoter's comment)

Comment: At last a useful use case for a `FULL JOIN` :D. Just for completeness, an empty result set would indicate that both tables are "equal", while the returned rows would point to the differences between them.